# how to make some components not scrollable?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to make some components inside react native not scrollable? As we can see, anytime all the components does not fit in a screen, it will make it auto scrollable. How do we prevent that behavior from happening? Is this case, how do we make those components circled in blue fixed in their locations? I tried putting them inside the header, but they dont show up.

[image]

```
        <Container>
        <Header>
        <Title>Form</Title>

        <Button transparent onPress={this.props.openDrawer}>
            <Icon name="ios-menu" />
        </Button>
        </Header>
        <Content>
            <List>
                <ListItem>
                <InputGroup>
                    <Icon name="ios-search-outline" size={30} />
                    <Input placeholder="What do you want to find? e.g. Restaurants" />
                </InputGroup>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <IconEntypo name="location-pin" size={30} />
                    <Text >Binondo, Manila</Text>
                </ListItem>
            </List>
            <XYZ_SearchList/>
        </Content>
    </Container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easily... Not sure whether you are using 3rd party lib or custom components, but I assume `List`, `Container` and/or `Content` components wrap `ScrollView` - which scroll by default.

Extract content out of this components, put content to be scrolled into scrollable component then. See following snippet - might require some changes

```
<View>
  <Header>
    <Title>Form</Title>
    <Button transparent onPress={this.props.openDrawer}>
        <Icon name="ios-menu" />
    </Button>
  </Header>

  <InputGroup>
    <Icon name="ios-search-outline" size={30} />
    <Input placeholder="What do you want to find? e.g. Restaurants" />
  </InputGroup>
  <View>
    <IconEntypo name="location-pin" size={30} />
    <Text >Binondo, Manila</Text>
  </View>

  <ScrollView>
    <XYZ_SearchList/>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```